# How to write ≙ in latex

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I want to use unicode character 2259 "estimates" in my document, but cannot find it in the symbols-a4 list or via [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org).

It looks exactly like this: ≙

The closest I get is \triangleq: ≜, but it has a different meaning.

Comment: Have you tried `$\stackrel{\wedge}{=}$` ?

Comment: Well, that was easy. I just expected that there is already a single existing command to produce the symbol since it's a standardized common expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @Werner While that question is certainly related, this does not look like a duplicate at all!

Comment: @schtandard: Why not? The OP is interested in a symbol and that symbol is available in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: @Werner True, however OP stated that they did not find it there (which may be their fault, but is likely to happen to others as well), it does not show up on Detexify, it is quite a common symbol (I think) and there are several good answers. I think this question should be the destination for people looking for this symbol.

Comment: @Werner in question is clearly mentioned `cannot find it in the symbols-a4 list or via detexify`, so in this case a valid answer would be how to find the symbol in symbol-a4 or detexify or how to build it otherwise, see given answers. It is no duplicate IMHO

Comment: @Mensch: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503902/5764) proves otherwise (that the symbol is in `symbols-a4`). Detexify would not always be accurate, and I'm not sure how often it is updated. For example, `\corresponds` may have been added recently (or more recent than what is loaded in Detexify).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `\overset` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\estimates}{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}{=}}

\begin{document}

$A\estimates B$

\end{document}
```

It won't work in sub/superscripts, but I don't think you need the symbol there.

[image]

A different realization is with

```
\newcommand{\estimates}{\mathrel{\hat{=}}}
```

that would produce

[image]

Answer (score 20):

With the package `fontspec`, you may call each symbol by its unicode. In this case, the command would be `$\symbol{"2259}$`. You just have to look for [fonts, which are giving you this symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2259/fontsupport.htm).

Here are 4 examples:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Example & Font\\ \midrule
$a\wedgeq b$ & Latin Modern Math\\
\setmathfont{xits-math}$a\wedgeq b$ & XITS Math\\
\setmathfont{asana-math}$a\wedgeq b$ & Asana Math\\
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math}$a\wedgeq b$ & TeX Gyre Pagella Math\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! unfortunately i am not using 'XeTeX or LuaTeX', but 'unicode-math' and 'font spec' require that...

Answer (score 18):

You can use STIX fonts if you don't mind.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix} % (Times style) Main fonts of the document will be changed

\begin{document}

$a \wedgeq b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Burcardo: It is possible to use only one symbol from the font package. But that's tricky. You can combine two symbols via `\stackrel` etc., although that isn't perfect.

Answer (score 4):

There are several packages listed in [`symbols-a4`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) that provide this command as `\corresponds`.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathabx}` and then `a \corresponds b` .